# Getting Illegal invocation error while using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting the below error while trying to use ajax call in Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at e (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/js/jquery.js:4:23990)
    at Vc (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/js/jquery.js:4:23875)
    at Vc (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/js/jquery.js:4:23898)
    at Function.m.param (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/js/jquery.js:4:24236)
    at Function.ajax (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/js/jquery.js:4:20195)
    at Function.m.(anonymous function) [as post] (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/js/jquery.js:4:22297)
    at saveAllManageSpaceData (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/listyourspace:1418:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (http://oditek.in/fyndspace/listyourspace:693:102)
```

My working code is given below

```
<button class="btn nextbtnbgdiv open6" type="button" onclick="saveAllManageSpaceData();">Save &amp; Continue <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>



var data={"city":city,"area":area,"list_name":list_name,"file_data":file_data,"stDate":stDate,"endDate":endDate,"address":address,"latitude":latitude,"longitude":longitude,"description":description,"tag_google_map":tag_google_map,"space_area":space_area,"space_status":space_status,"price":price,"sPrice":sPrice,"price_type":price_type,"booth_size":booth_size,"height":height,"width":width,"spaceAccess":spaceAccess,"rules":rules,"Overview":Overview,"depositeForLoss":depositeForLoss,"dkeyAccess":dkeyAccess};
console.log('hello',data);
var url="common.php?action=saveManageSpace";
$.post(url,data,function(data){
    console.log('res',data);
});
```

Here I am getting the above  error while using ajax call. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Show the click event handler and the element you clicked

Comment: @mplungjan : Please check my post again.

Answer (score 0):

your data is an object - you might want to try as array

```
 var data=[{"city":city,"area":area,"list_name":list_name,"file_data":file_data,"stDate":stDate,"endDate":endDate,"address":address,"latitude":latitude,"longitude":longitude,"description":description,"tag_google_map":tag_google_map,"space_area":space_area,"space_status":space_status,"price":price,"sPrice":sPrice,"price_type":price_type,"booth_size":booth_size,"height":height,"width":width,"spaceAccess":spaceAccess,"rules":rules,"Overview":Overview,"depositeForLoss":depositeForLoss,"dkeyAccess":dkeyAccess}];
```